# How to use the name of a vector resulting from a fuction as data in another fuction?

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a array (ar) and want to delete several rows according to the result of a function.

**Data**

structure(c(0, 11, 17, 15, 22, 67, 73, 68, 31, 31, 28, 33, 34,
32, 11, 0, 9, 12, 21, 67, 73, 67, 35, 30, 34, 67, 60, 36, 17,
9, 0, 6, 19, 70, 74, 68, 36, 36, 36, 64, 66, 39, 15, 12, 6, 0,
13, 64, 69, 66, 34, 37, 39, 77, 65, 45, 22, 21, 19, 13, 0, 59,
60, 66, 38, 39, 39, 40, 43, 43, 67, 67, 70, 64, 59, 0, 10, 18,
77, 75, 78, 93, 93, 85, 73, 73, 74, 69, 60, 10, 0, 15, 76, 74,
80, 103, 101, 95, 68, 67, 68, 66, 66, 18, 15, 0, 59, 65, 73,
90, 87, 82, 31, 35, 36, 34, 38, 77, 76, 59, 0, 8, 19, 24, 28,
32, 31, 30, 36, 37, 39, 75, 74, 65, 8, 0, 12, 20, 22, 23, 28,
34, 36, 39, 39, 78, 80, 73, 19, 12, 0, 6, 14, 18, 33, 67, 64,
77, 40, 93, 103, 90, 24, 20, 6, 0, 2, 8, 34, 60, 66, 65, 43,
93, 101, 87, 28, 22, 14, 2, 0, 6, 32, 36, 39, 45, 43, 85, 95,
82, 32, 23, 18, 8, 6, 0), .Dim = c(14L, 14L))

After counting the values of each vector smaller than 25, the vector (the first) with more values smaller than 25 is selected.

```
a<-colSums(ar<25)
b<-which.max(a)
```

After this operations I obtain b = 10, indicating that [,10] is the vector with more values smaller than 25.
Now I want to use the obtained vector to perform the following operation: to subset the array.

```
c<-subset(df,b<"25")
```

And from this operation I expect to exclude from the array the rows where [,10] has values smaller than 25. I have use the reference b in the last function but it does not work.

How can I refer to the resultant vector from a function?

Comment: What is `td` in the example.  Use `[[` i.e. `td[td[[b]] >32, ]`

Comment: @akrun is is actually df instead of dt

Comment: Instead of `subset`, you can use `df[df[[b]] > 32,, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @akrun what if instead of a data-frame I have an array for the same operation

Comment: If it is a matrix, then you need `m1[m1[, b]> 32,, drop = FALSE]`